# operator does not exist for timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

I am new to Grafana and have a (probably simple) problem:

I create a variable in Grafana as:
`SELECT to_char("date", 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM my.database;` The variable is named `date_as_date`.
The `date` variable is a timestamp in the postgre database.
I have to formate the date manually, otherwise Grafana returns it as INT (unix timestamp), which is highly inconvenient when you want to select a specific date.

In a panel I also want to filter on this new variable:

```
SELECT 
  "date",
  "MWNR",
  "Umlauf_ID",
FROM my.database
WHERE "MWNR" = $selectMWNR AND to_char("date", 'DD-MM-YYYY') = $date_as_date;
```

When I do that I get the error:
```db query error: pq: operator does not exist: text = integer````

Any ideas how to fix this or even how to avoid Grafana's conversion to INT from the timestamp?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  SQL syntax can vary across different DBMS's, in particular, conversion functions tend to differ.

Comment: My DBMS is a Postgre SQL data base

Comment: @Max86, this information should be provided by using appropriate tags on the question, not in the comments. Comments are considered ephemeral, and should not contain information critical for question.

Answer (score 2):

> how to fix this

To convert date to needed format you can use following syntax: `${date_as_date:date:DD-MM-YYYY}` as described [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__from-and-__to).

> how to avoid Grafana's conversion to INT from the timestamp

I believe Grafana stores dates as integer timestamps, so no way.

But I advise to consider possibility of using integer values in your queries, as oppose to your current attempt of using formatted strings. How it can be done depends on DBMS in use, as syntax and available functions vary heavily.
For example in MySQL this would look something like this:

```sql
WHERE "MWNR" = $selectMWNR AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP("date") = $date_as_date
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

For the first suggestion I still get the same error:
```db query error: pq: operator does not exist: text = integer```

For the second one I get:
```db query error: pq: function unix_timestamp(date) does not exist```

I use Grafana version 9.

Comment: @Max86, regarding first: use drop down on the panel > inspect > query. Check what causes an error (using client for database). It might be that you need additional quotes around variable, like this `"${date_as_date:....}"`. Regarding second: I wrote that this is for MySQL. Postgre has it's own functions for working with dates.